# Mapping an Array using Fluent N Hibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I am not sure if fluent n hibernate can do this or not, but I cannot figure out how.

I have a table - **cases** and some properties

ownerId, brokerId, shipperId

I want to map this to my property:

int[] OrgsWithAccess

Is this possible?

This way when I am checking if an org has access to the case, I can check the property OrgsWithAccess rather than OwnerId == myorg.id or brokerId == myorg.id etc.

Comment: what field in the table makes up the `int` array? How will NHibernate update other properties of `OrgsWithAccess` for consistency, if each row in the database is only represented as an `int` in an array in the application?

Comment: The fields on the database are ownerid, brokerid, shipperid, same as the class property names

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I wouldn't recommend trying to map in the way that you have asked.

`cases` table looks like it is some form of junction table between other tables. I'll assume that these other tables each contain data that are represented as entities in the application, and that there are three tables, `Owner`, `Broker` and `Shipper`.

`OrgsWithAccess` should be mapped using the references to the entities that is has in the application i.e. assume the class looks something like

```
public class OrgsWithAccess
{
    public virtual Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual Broker { get; set; }

    public virtual Shipper { get; set; }
}
```

Then the mapping will look like

```
public class OrgsWithAccessMap : ClassMap<OrgsWithAccess>
{
    public OrgsWithAccessMap()
    {
        References(x => x.Owner);
        References(x => x.Broker);
        References(x => x.Shipper);
    }
}
```

Then when querying, you would simply look at the properties on `OrgsWithAccess`

```
session.QueryOver<OrgsWithAccess>().Where(x => x.Owner.Id == id);
```